# Cloud Zoom and jQuery mouseleave()

Tags: jquery, zooming

I'm creating a zoom function for product viewing using [Cloud Zoom](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/cloud-zoom.htm) and I want to activate the zoom on mouse click (which works fine), however when I try and add functionality to close the zoom on mouse leave there are these 'glitches' that I can't seem to get my head around - If I leave the container for the init area very slowly I can trigger the closing script. But if I drag the mouse rather fast to another part of the page nothing happens.

HTML

```
<div id="product-image">
  <a href="images/product-sample-zoom.jpg" class="cloud-zoom" rel="adjustX: 10, adjustY: -4"><img src="images/product-sample.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var $zoomInit = false;
$('.cloud-zoom').click(function(e) {
  $('.cloud-zoom').CloudZoom({ showTitle: false });
  $zoomInit = true;
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('#product-image').mouseout(function() {
  if ($zoomInit == true) {
    $('.cloud-zoom').data('zoom').destroy();
    $zoomInit = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had thew exact same problem.

in the cloud-zoom.1.0.2.min.js look for this function:

(if it's minified just search for "mouseleave", there is only one function.)

```
$mouseTrap.bind('mouseleave',this,function(event){
    clearTimeout(controlTimer);
    if(lens){
        lens.fadeOut(299)
    }
    if($tint){
        $tint.fadeOut(299)
    }if(softFocus){
        softFocus.fadeOut(299)
    }
    zoomDiv.fadeOut(300,
        function(){
            ctx.fadedOut()
        });
    return false
});
```

Returning false seems to be the problem. Removing it or using "event.preventDefault();" instead works.

Comment: I see this error occassionally across some browsers in my JavaScript logging utility, but I never see the error myself. I too am using Cloud Zoom v1.0.2, and I have learned earlier today that they do not support this version any longer and have now moved on to v3 (http://www.starplugins.com/checkout/). I have tried removing the `return false` and it has no adverse effect on FF, IE7/8/9, Chrome, Mobile Safari on iPhone or iPad so that is good. However, I will need to wait until it can be tested on all browsers to verify if this is the fix. Thanks for sharing, though.